# IOS 8 facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook

i am working with the HelloFacebookSample from face book's sdk.

i have a few issues, but am trying to get through them.

The one i have right now is that after I login, then logout, then login again, i am automatically logged in without being asked for credentials.  Is there any way to change this behavior?

And secondly (for now), is there any way i can bring up the FB login dialog within my app instead of it going to Safari? i don't want my users to have access to safari at all, so i need to keep control.

The original FB sdk (about 2 years old) handled the login directly from within the app, so I am thinking i am just missing something here?

Thanks,

Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full control over the login process then you can't use the SDK, you need to add and manage a web view yourself. Facebook tries to bother the user to reconfirm as little as possible, so it will provide a login with the least path of resistance (and user taps / interaction).

Depending on how the user is logged into Facebook you won't be able to force them to re-enter login details unless you implement the web view approach. If you're using the SDK then you would need to call `closeAndClearTokenInformation` on the active session and also delete any Facebook related cookies from the app (and that's probably as close as you can get).

Comment: Hi Wain, and thanks for responding. So this is a different mechanism than the "old" Facebook SDK had? I am somewhat ok with that - so i need as ask if there is any way *other* than a WEBView? seems that may be a bit much to try and set up, no? I am new to Xcode and IOS programming (although a lot of other coding experience).  Thanks!! Jerry

Comment: Why do you want to force a new login? The theory kind of goes that the device belongs to one user and thus one FB account.

Comment: this app is a 'commercial' app - like a kiosk - and each picture posted needs to go to that persons' FB account. I don't WANT a one-user / one-device.. i need one-device / MANY-users

Comment: Then you shouldn't use the SDK. You should use an in-app web view so you can purge all cookies and force the login UI to appear, then use the web interface to FB to upload your content.

Comment: ok - thats what i was afraid you were going to say :)  Thanks for the clarification. (I don't have enough points to vote this answer up...).